# AsyncHttpClient sending HTTP POST request to server

Tags: android

I'm trying to send to my server HTTP POST request.
My server accept a curl like this:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"City\":\"Lodz\", \"FirstName\":\"Patryk\"}" http://127.0.0.1:8000/addemployees
```

I'm also trying to be able to send HTTP POST request using Android.
My code looks like this:

```
 AsyncHttpClient httpClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
 httpClient.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
 RequestParams jsonParams = new RequestParams();
 jsonParams.put("City", city);
 jsonParams.put("FirstName", city);
 Log.i("requestParams: ", jsonParams.toString());
 httpClient.post("http://myComputerIP:8000/addemployees", jsonParams, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

 @Override
 public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject obj) {
      String jsonResponse = obj.toString();
      Log.i("TAG", "onSuccess: " + jsonResponse);
      }

 @Override
 public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
      Log.e("TAG", "onFailure: " + errorResponse);
}
```

However, there's something wrong in my Android code because I get this error:

```
TAG: onFailure: {"message":"Internal Server Error"}
```

I've tried several solutions but none of them worked. How should I change it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should send your data in a JSON format. For that you need to pass to your `POST` method a `StringEntity` object that contains your already formatted JSON string instead of a `RequestParams`.

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("City", city);
json.put("FirstName", city);
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json.toString());
```